# Simple analog AM radio generating noise throughout circuit

Tags: analog, noise, radio, amplitude-modulation

I'm building a simple AM radio circuit for one of my classes. It works insofar as that anywhere from 400 Hz - 4 kHz we get a nice AM radioey tone. But when the outputs are connected to an oscilloscope, noise is generated. I've attached below a picture of said noise, the schematic, and a simple block diagram.

Connecting the output of any block's output starting from "Band Pass Filter 1" generates a lot of noise. In lieu of this, we had connected large capacitors (47 μF) to the positive and negative terminals of the op-amps we were using (op27's) to try and clean up most of the noise.

In the picture below, you will see how the noise is seen as rough and jagged peaks. We see the clean signal we want on the bottom shown as a slightly thicker blue line. Some form of this exact noise was seen in almost every blocks output.

Any suggestions I can shoot at this proverbial circuit monster will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Noise. When not paused imagine a thick blue line from the bottom to the peak of the noise. N]

[image: Schematic as seen in LTSpice. Note, many resistance values were changed when building in a real-world environment.]

[image: Instead of a BNC Cable to connect between breadboards, we instead used a jumper cable.]

Comment: Digital scopes lie. What does the 'noise' look like at eg. 5us/div? Please show us a photo of the actual circuit.

Comment: It *could* be some stage self oscillating due to stability issues in the stages. Have you put bypass capacitors on the supplies? Opamps really don't like when they are starved in slew. If your 47µF is not ceramic it wouldn't help for that. Also verify that the OP27 has enough GBWP for the BP filters, it's easy to forget about that

Comment: where does the supply voltage for your circuitry come from?

Comment: also, hm, modern scope, 1970s opamp... might have a simpler life by not using the OP27, which is probably far less ideal than its modern alternatives. (also, no need for dual +-12 V supply to amplify a µV signal to a mV to 1 V signal)

Comment: And where was the probe connected when you took the picture. This isn't nice to know, it's a showstopper not knowing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the comments/suggestions. Here's how we fixed it! Today when my lab partner and I connected all the cables to start diagnosing the problem, the signal ended up fixing itself. On second inspection, we realized that some of the cables we used to connect from the power supply to the breadboard itself were bad. After switching those cables out the signal was PERFECT! Picture below of our final circuit!

[image: Full circuit in all its jumper cable glory]